# How to rotate multiple RigidBodies in a prefab based on user input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, unity3d-mirror, prefab

I'm currently trying to rotate different `Rigidbody`s in a prefab based on separate inputs. I have it working when each `Rigidbody` has a separate script attached to it with the designated input, but I need to combine them into one "master control" script so I can eventually split the player character in half vertically so 1 player can control the left half and 1 player can control the right half of the body's limbs within the Mirror Networking API.

The working code is only attached to a single limb, in this case, the left bicep. The only thing that changes between limbs is the keyboard input and the multiplier variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeftBicep : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float amount = 6000f;
    protected Rigidbody rb;
    public float multiplier = 4f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("leftbicep") * amount * Time.deltaTime;

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(Vector3.right * h * multiplier); 
    }
}
```

And here's the "master control" script that is attached to the full body prefab that I can't get to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody forearmL;
    public Rigidbody forearmR;
    public Rigidbody shoulderL;
    public Rigidbody shoulderR;
    public Rigidbody thighL;
    public Rigidbody thighR;
    public Rigidbody legL;
    public Rigidbody legR;

    public float amount = 6000f;
    public float multiplier = 4f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        forearmL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftForearm2");
        forearmR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightForearm2");
        shoulderL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftBicep2");
        shoulderR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightBicep2");
        thighL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftThigh2");
        thighR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightThigh2");
        legL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftLeg2");
        legR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightLeg2");
        
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
            float lBicep = Input.GetAxis("leftbicep") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            shoulderL.AddTorque(Vector3.right * lBicep * multiplier);

            float lFArm = Input.GetAxis("leftforearm") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            forearmL.AddTorque(Vector3.right * lFArm * multiplier);
            
            float lThigh = Input.GetAxis("leftthigh") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            thighL.AddTorque(Vector3.right * lThigh * multiplier);
            
            float lLeg = Input.GetAxis("leftleg") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            legL.AddTorque(Vector3.right * lLeg * multiplier);

            float rBicep = Input.GetAxis("rightbicep") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            shoulderR.AddTorque(Vector3.right * rBicep * multiplier);
            
            float rFArm = Input.GetAxis("rightforearm") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            forearmR.AddTorque(Vector3.right * rFArm * multiplier);
            
            float rThigh = Input.GetAxis("rightthigh") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            thighR.AddTorque(Vector3.right * rThigh * multiplier);
            
            float rLeg = Input.GetAxis("rightleg") * amount * Time.deltaTime;
            legR.AddTorque(Vector3.right * rLeg * multiplier);

            
    }
}
```

The exception I get when running the game with the player prefab that has the "master control" script in the scene is

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Movement.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/test/Movement.cs:38)
```

How do I go about getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your issue is that all of these

```
forearmL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftForearm2");
forearmR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightForearm2");
shoulderL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftBicep2");
shoulderR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightBicep2");
thighL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftThigh2");
thighR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightThigh2");
legL = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("LeftLeg2");
legR = (Rigidbody)GetComponent("RightLeg2");
```

will return `null` since the component you are looking for is called `Rigidbody` .. not `LeftForearm2` etc. see [`GetComponent(string type)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

> type
>      The **type** of Component to retrieve.

---

Just make all references in the exposed fields via the Unity Inspector and remove your `Start` method entirely!

Or alternatively it sounds like what you passed into the `GetComponent` is actually the name of your child objects nested directly under the main controller so you could do (but I wouldn't as said)

```
// See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html
forearmL = transform.Find("LeftForearm2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
forearmR = transform.Find("RightForearm2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
shoulderL = transform.Find("LeftBicep2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
shoulderR = transform.Find("RightBicep2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
thighL = transform.Find("LeftThigh2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
thighR = transform.Find("RightThigh2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
legL = transform.Find("LeftLeg2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
legR = transform.Find("RightLeg2").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```